# Okta Self User Registration page not showing up

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am trying to add the sign up link to my okta login widget. I had aded the user registration policy in the okta admin dashboard. But when i am clicking on the Sign Up link it shows an empty dailog box.

On inspecting in console i got this error.

```
{"errorCode":"E0000007","errorSummary":"Not found: Resource not found: 0oahy3194bQu0CKAD0h7 (UserRegistrationPolicy)","errorLink":"E0000007","errorId":"oae2fIZi7s3SBanTYQBXE77tQ","errorCauses":[]}
```

I followed this link to add the user registration policy 
https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Directory/Directory_Self_Service_Registration.htm

I had configured the sign in widget in my Angular App using this code:

```
    var signInWidgetConfig = {
          // Enable or disable widget functionality with the following options. Some of these features require additional configuration in your Okta admin settings. Detailed information can be found here: https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget#okta-sign-in-widget
          // Look and feel changes:
          logo: '//logo.clearbit.com/okta.com', // Try changing "okta.com" to other domains, like: "workday.com", "splunk.com", or "delmonte.com"
          language: 'en',                       // Try: [fr, de, es, ja, zh-CN] Full list: https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget#language-and-text
          i18n: {
            //Overrides default text when using English. Override other languages by adding additional sections.
            'en': {
              'primaryauth.title': 'Sign In',   // Changes the sign in text
              'primaryauth.submit': 'Sign In',  // Changes the sign in button
              // More e.g. [primaryauth.username.placeholder,  primaryauth.password.placeholder, needhelp, etc.].
              // Full list here: https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget/blob/master/packages/@okta/i18n/dist/properties/login.properties
            }
          },
          // Changes to widget functionality
          features: {
            registration: true,                 // Enable self-service registration flow
            rememberMe: true,                   // Setting to false will remove the checkbox to save username
            //multiOptionalFactorEnroll: true,  // Allow users to enroll in multiple optional factors before finishing the authentication flow.
            //selfServiceUnlock: true,          // Will enable unlock in addition to forgotten password
            //smsRecovery: true,                // Enable SMS-based account recovery
            //callRecovery: true,               // Enable voice call-based account recovery
            router: false                       // Leave this set to true for the API demo
          },
          authScheme:'SESSION',
          baseUrl: sampleConfig.oidc.issuer.split('/oauth2')[0],
          clientId: sampleConfig.oidc.clientId,
          redirectUri: sampleConfig.oidc.redirectUri,
          authParams: {
            responseType: ['id_token', 'token'],
            issuer: sampleConfig.oidc.issuer,
            display: 'page',
            scopes: sampleConfig.oidc.scope.split(' '),
          },
        };
        this.signIn = new OktaSignIn(signInWidgetConfig);


Please help me in this.
```